# Updating View in .edmx does not show the added additional Column

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made changes in View i.e Added one more column to it in DB and i want to take the Update of .edmx by following the procedure such as 
1.Going into Modal Browser and Deleting it and taking the Update from Update wizard and it shows the same View but with no presence of the added Column in DB
2.Refreshing the particular View from the second tab provided in Update wizard
But still not getting the new Column in the view.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same Problem .But I added Updated Column In Model Manually.
e.g. added MediCharges In My Database.then i added Model also. and i will get intellicense updated.

hope it well work for those who got same error .